# Java create collection and count of occurrences

Tags: java

I have a text file with each row representing a timezone. timezone.txt

I want my program to go row by row and count the number of timezones in the entire file.

sample:

```
Eastern 
Eastern 
West 
Eastern 
West 
West 
Eastern 
Mountain
West
```

Then give me a list of with timezone and number of occurances

```
[(West, 4), (Eastern, 4), (Mountain, 1)]
```

The number of distinct time zones are unknown at program start. My code so far can only print each timezone as it comes up but not sure how to make this array in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("timezones.txt"));

        String line = null;
        while ( (line = in.readLine() ) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Map<String, Integer>.

Comment: you could have tried something inside while loop before posting.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Map<String, Integer>` to store the count associated with each time zone. When you read a time zone name, retrieve the `Integer` stored under that name (if any), increment it, and store the updated count back in the map. If the name does not occur in the map, store a count of 1. When you're done, you can retrieve all the `<String, Integer>` entries and print your list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use map like `Map<String, Integer>` where, where key will be `String` and value will be `Integer`. Than loop through the file and put the `String` into `Map` and count the value.

```
 while ( (line = in.readLine() ) != null) {
    Integer count= map.get(line);
    map.put(line, count == null ? 1 : count+1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdas:

```
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("timezones.txt"))) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        in.lines().forEach(line -> {
            Integer count = map.get(line);
            map.put(line, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
        });
        System.out.println(map);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or using for:

```
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String line; null != (line = in.readLine()); ) {
            Integer count = map.get(line);
            map.put(line, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
```